# I'm working on a viewbot for nimo.tv using chrome headless but when i reach 350 views my views reset to 20

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm working on a view bot for nimo.tv using chrome headless
but when I reach 350 views my views reset to 20.
I tried most of the things to bypass detection so is there any way you know how to bypass it?
I use diff proxy for every instance of web driver with loop.
views usually reset if I try to push over 380 views which is the 11th instance of the webserver.